# Finger bones not moving in line with hand?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, weight-painting

I've been rigging away at a model of mine and can't seem to get the hand and fingers to line up out of all the bones so far.

I've tinkered with the weights on the hand and fingers but can never get them to line up.

Here's the paint of the hand for reference, and the fingers not painted are of course painted in their own individual groups.

[image: Hands seem to be painted red inward, and lighten up near the fingers.]

Main issue is I try to move the hand and and the finger's mesh is always lingering behind/ahead.

[image: Default Position]

And when rotating...

[image: Lingering]

Why is exactly might this be happening? I never had other bones fail me so far, and I've place nearly 300 of them!

What I hope is to have healthy-working bones like the ones here:

[image: Hand]

[image: Actually functional]

Any ideas on how to fix this? To clarify, I **don't want to have to redo the entire mesh.**

That simply won't do, but I'm willing to redo the entire hand and use automatic weights at least there if it means not deleting the whole rig entirely.

Thanks for hearing me out!

Comment: so this part of your hand has an influence that it is not supposed to have, hard to tell more, maybe share your file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out I simply had two bones, that being the "hand" bone and the smaller "hand adjustment" bone overlap with identical weight values, making the overall hand mesh move 'faster' than the fingers!

I just had to remove the weights from the adjustment bone altogether and it works as intended:

[image: The hand works!]

Answer (score 1):

To me it looks like your fingzrs are influenced by several bones more than they should be.

Each vertex has an influence vale between zero and one. Bones influencing the same vertex can share the incluence valur, i.e. 0,3 for one and 0,7 for another. The total is always 1.
If a veetex is influenced by several bones and the addotion of the influences is >1, there will be issues.

Go in weight paint mode and make sure nothings wrongly influenced by a bone that shouldn't. Also, you can use the weight normalization tools to help you keep influences ≤1.